# iscroll4 prevents keyboard display on focus on an extern input (android/ios)

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, iscroll4

I have a problem with iScroll on android (2.2/2.3 and ios)

I have a code which looks like :

```
<input id = "thing" val=""/>
    <div id="scroller" style="overflow:auto; height:150px;">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="thing">thing</a></li>
            <li><a class="thing">thing</a></li>
            <li><a class="thing">thing</a></li>
            <li><a class="thing">thing</a></li>
            <li><a class="thing">thing</a></li>
            <li><a class="thing">thing</a></li>
            <li><a class="thing">thing</a></li>
            <li><a class="thing">thing</a></li>
            <li><a class="thing">thing</a></li>
            <li><a class="thing">thing</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a class="thing">thing</a>
```

and the js :

```
$( document ).ready( function(e) {
    var testScroll = new iScroll('scroller', {vScrollbar: false});
    $('a.thing').on('click', function(){$('#thing').focus();});
};
```

when I click on the lone link, I give focus on #thing input and the soft keyboard appear.
when I click on those in the scroller, focus is given but the keyboard don't appear.

I really don't understand what don't works here. I'd like to make the keyboard appear.

edit: I'm using jquery mobile, if that can help helping me.

Answer (score 0):

try to tell if the target is an input element, modify the '_start' function in iscroll.js:

```
_start: function (e) {
    var that = this,
    point = hasTouch ? e.changedTouches[0] : e,
    matrix;

    that.moved = false;

    if ( e.target.tagName == "SELECT" || e.target.tagName == "INPUT"
        || e.target.tagName == "BUTTON" || e.target.tagName == "TEXTAREA") {
        return true;
    }

    e.preventDefault();

    // more codes here

}
```

Comment: the target is a link here, , but yeah, whith "onBeforeScrollStart: function (e) { if(target.tagName != 'A')e.preventDefault(); }", it works. but I'm not really happy with this kind of trick.

Comment: i think it is a bug of iScroll, if iScroll prevent all default event  when touch start, it must cause something weird.

Comment: yeah... what I don't understand is why the click and focus event are fired but not completly. I'll take a little WE time to go deeper into the code to understand that. edit: I forgot e. before target in my edit: "onBeforeScrollStart: function (e) { if(e.target.tagName != 'A')e.preventDefault(); }"